# Headphone jack isn't working on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Lenovo ideapad 330)

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, lenovo, microphone, headphones

Device Information:

```
Hardware Model- Lenovo ideapad 330-15IKB
Memory- 8 GB
Processor- Intel Core i5-8250 CPU @ 1.60GHz x 8
Graphics- NV138/ Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
Disk Capacity- 1 TB

OS Name- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
OS Type- 64-bit
GNOME version- 42.5
Windowing System- Wayland
```

As the title suggest, I'm having problem with the headphone jack. I have already tried to follow the steps mentioned in the other answers for this same question, none of them quite worked or they seem like a very old solutions which isn't working anymore. I tried the `$ alsactl restore`, it didn't work. I also edited `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and added these lines,

```
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-instel model=auto
```

also, I set the model as `dell-m6-amic` and `lenovo-ideapad-330` (dell one was mentioned in the solution and lenovo one is because of my device.

I then tried with the `pavucontrol` even though I can use my headphone now but the microphone isn't working, also I'm looking for a permanent solution.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm having problem with the headphone jack"?

Comment: I have explained the whole issue, so I hope you get it.